# Is one of my heat zones not heating because of a valve problem?

Tags: plumbing, heating

One zone isn't heating and I'm trying to figure out why before calling for assistance. The pump is running, the thermostat is working, and the pipes are hot but only really hot on the left side of the valve, the right side is what I could call warm. I fully turned it counter-clockwise until it started to drop but that didn't help much so should I just get this replaced? Could it be something else and this is a red herring? It's been cold too, could there be a blockage from ice somewhere too?

[image: the valve in question]

Comment: Did that start leaking when you turned it or was it doing that before?  Is there a spigot/faucet on the return for that zone?  I would start by hooking up a hose to the return for that zone and adding water to the system (close the return value back to the system as well).  If it's not flowing out the hose as you are adding water, then it's a blockage of some sort.  If there is a lot of air bubbles, then air is probably the issue.  If everything appears normal and it still doesn't work after shutting off the spigot, I'd think it was the pump.

Answer (score 1):

The knob on the top (at least for the Taco valves I know) is not an open/close but rather an adjustment to the open position.  Here's a cross-section diagram.

[image: taco valve].

It's possible there is a lot of crud which is either blocking flow, or causing the valve to be stuck closed.  (which is rare; usually these things get stuck open). Try backing the screw out as far as you can, and maybe tap gently on the body of the valve with a mallet to see if that frees up the flow.
If not, you can take off the entire top to clean it (take a wrench to that bolt) , but be sure to drain the pipes first unless you like fountains in your basement :-)

Comment: Please source your image

Comment: @FreeMan  sorry  -- I just grabbed on of many identical drawings off Google Image Search.

Comment: People used to get on that pretty harshly, it's backed off a bit in recent times. Most pics here are from homeowners supplying obviously self-taken pics of their own property...